# Chromium build fails due to `out of memory` allocation

Tags: 12.04, chromium, ram, swap

I am trying to build chromium `content_shell`. But it fails at the last linking stage because of `out of memory`.

**Error Log:**

```
[1/1] LINK content_shell     

...

/usr/bin/ld: out of memory allocating 1000 bytes after a total of 2115682304 bytes                                          
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status                           
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

**Solution I found was to add more swap:**

> *It takes about 8GB of swap file to link chromium and its tests. If you get an out-of-memory error during the final link, you will need to add swap space with swapon. It's recommended to have at least 4GB of memory available for building a statically linked debug build. Dynamic linking and/or building a release build lowers memory requirements. People with less than 8GB of memory may want to not build tests since they are quite large. (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructionsPrerequisites)*

**Before adding swap:**

```
rna@rna-P580:~/workspace/blink_ref/src$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3899        684       3215          0          2        105
-/+ buffers/cache:        576       3323
Swap:         3954        534       3420
```

**After swap increased:**

```
rna@rna-P580:/dev$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3899        567       3331          0          1         70
-/+ buffers/cache:        495       3403
Swap:        12050        577      11473
```

**Problem :**

I still have the same `out of memory` failure even after I increased swap by 8GB.
How should I fix this problem?

Comment: If I recall correctly, `content_shell` are tests for Chromium to make sure it works correctly; this isn't the actual Chromium browser. Are you sure you want to build this? Also, are you building in Debug mode or Release mode? Are you including the symbols in the binaries?